# How to dynamically add a new property to array of object inside v-for - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add on extra property(`showMore`) dynamically to array of object inside v-for. is it possible to do it inside `v-for` like:

```
this.students = [
{
 name: 'anonymous',
 class: 'Sixth',
 otherInfo: "..."
},
{
 name: 'anonymous2',
 class: 'Sixth',
 otherInfo: "..."
}
]
<div v-for="student in students">
  <div>{{student.name}}</div>
  <div>{{student.class}}</div>
  <div @click="student.showMore = true">Show more +</div> 
  <!-- it was possible in angularjs. is it possible in vuejs ?-->
</div>
```

here i am adding one more property (`showMore`) to array of object(`student`) by clicking on Show more. is it possible inside v-for? if not then how to achieve this(with best practice)?

Comment: I looking for same thing.Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @SavanS Please check my answer

Answer (score 8):

Sure, but it will not be reactive though. If you want that, you need to use:

```
vm.$set( target, key, value )
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 6):

use `Vue.set(obj, property, value);`

**Detailed example:**

```
this.students = [
{
 name: 'anonymous',
 class: 'Sixth',
 otherInfo: "..."
},
{
 name: 'anonymous2',
 class: 'Sixth',
 otherInfo: "..."
}
]
<div v-for="student in students">
  <div>{{student.name}}</div>
  <div>{{student.class}}</div>
  <div @click="showMore(student)">Show more +</div> 
  <!-- it was possible in angularjs. is it possible in vuejs ?-->
</div>

showMore(student) {
  Vue.set(student, 'showMore', true);
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to import `Vue`

Comment: Correct. This works for me. Also, according to Vue's documentation, `Vue.set` must be used to add new properties to reactive objects. Read more [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: yes it works for  me . ```Vue.set(object, 'key','value');```

Answer (score -2):

If you are targeting modern browsers, you can always use the summary tag:

```
<details>
  <summary>More Info</summary>
  <p>hello!</p>
</details>
```